# Rlwrap doesn't seem to cooperate with "read -e"

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, readline

A new twist to somewhat common question:

In my interactive script I pre-fill the user input like so:

```
#process_line.sh

INPUT=$1 # previous value
read -e -p "> " -i "$INPUT" INPUT
```

To implement command history I call `process_line.sh`

```
    rlwrap ./process_line.sh $INPUT
```

Now here's the twist: if I have the `"read -e"` option, I can edit the pre-filled input BUT there is no command history, and adversely, I can have command history, courtesy of `rlwrap` , without the `"read -e"` option, but no pre-filling (that is, `"read -i"` doesn't really do anything).

The question, of course, is whether I can have both input pre-fill and editing AND command history at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off the `-e` to read.  Then the two readline implementations won't clash.

To get the prompt, you can pass `-S "> "` to rlwrap.

Comment: if I turn the `-e` off then I lose the input editing. Not sure what you mean by `-S`, doesn't seem to be a valid option (Cygwin, bash version 4.1.10)

Comment: rlwrap supports line editing directly (and rlwrap has the -S argument -- realized my response wasnt clear)

Comment: Sorry, `-S` doesn't work for me: 
`rlwrap: error: unknown option -- S
try 'rlwrap --help' for more information`
You are suggesting it should look something like this?
`rlwrap -S $INPUT ./process_line.sh`

Comment: `rlwrap -S "> "  -P "$INPUT" ./process_line.sh "$INPUT"` with the script running `read INPUT`.  read the rlwrap manpage.  Does it support the `-S` option?

Comment: Yes I've been all over the man page :) You seem to have a totally different version of rlwrap, mine has the following options:
`Options:
   -a, --always-readline[=password:] 
   -b, --break-chars <chars>
   -c, --complete-filenames
   -C, --command-name <name|N>
   -f, --file <file>
   -h, --help
   -H, --history-filename <file>
   -i, --case-insensitive
   -l, --logfile <file>
   -n, --no-warnings
   -m, --multi-line[=newline substitute] 
   -r, --remember
   -v, --version
   -s, --histsize <size>  (negative: readonly)`

Neither -S nor -P options exist... Looks like I am stuck!

Comment: ooh I'm looking at the ubuntu version.  And it looks like cygwin rlwrap is really old: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-08/msg00593.html

Comment: Alright this explains it. I suppose I'll try to compile the newest version, although this will be a hit for portability. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This use case has been in the rlwrap manual from version 0.25 onwards; how exactly to go about it depends a bit on the rlwrap version.

In rlwrap 0.37 you do it like this:

INPUT=$(rlwrap -o -S ">" -P $INPUT cat)

The advantage of this approach is that every input variable can be given its own history and completion list (using the -f and -H options)

The cygwin version (0.24) is indeed ancient, but compiling rlwrap yourself should be painless. If you want to you can build a statically linked version (see the INSTALL file for instructions) and distribute it along with your script.

Comment: I chickened out and got my friend (who is actually doing programming for living) to help me implement this in Python. This is going to help the portability if anything, and adds the possibility to stick a GUI on top of this.. I realise this is probably a more complicated solution than distributing a complied rlwrap with the script, but since I do this as a hobby I don't mind! Thanks anyway!